# Is it possible to abort post update in Wodpress if specific conditions on metadata are met?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type which has some metadata to check in order to be saved or updated. Now I would like to know if it's possible to abort the post creation or update if the check on metadata fails.

To give a simple context and fix the idea, let's say my custom post has a metabox with two date input, let's call them date_start and date_end. When the user try to publish or update the post in the backend I would like to check those metadata and if date_start >= date_end the process aborts without actually update or insert the post into the database. The logic I'm trying to achieve would be something like this:

```
add_action( 'before_updating_post', check_metadata );

function check_metadata() {
  if ( condition ) {
    continue post save/update
  } else {
    abort post save/update // The post will not be saved/updated
  }
}
```

Where 'before_updating_post' is a fantasy name for an hook which allows me to abort the process of updating the post.

I've looked at some questions related to post update hooks but was unable to find some which allows to abort the process being most of them related to data manipulation before saving.

Comment: check the below link. you may find a answer from it. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42013/prevent-post-from-being-published-if-custom-fields-not-filled

Comment: Thank you @Raa, I've already checked this and similar questions, unfortunately the save_post hook is fired after the post has already been saved: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/.

Comment: 'wp_insert_post_data'

Comment: Thanks @MagentaCuda, could you give an example about how to abort updating inside the filter if a condition is met?

Comment: Since, this is a filter you need to abuse it by calling wp_die() otherwise the post will still be inserted or updated. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die

Comment: In the HTML you can have a link back to the edit post page.Alternatively, if you want to do this really nicely you can add an admin notice and do a wp_redirect() so you can avoid the ugly (unprofessional) page sent by wp_die().

Comment: A HUGE thank you @MagentaCuda!

Comment: On further thought, I would change your approach save it anyway but change the status to draft and add an admin notice that the save post has an error and needs correction. I think this would require less complex code than actually not saving it.

Comment: That was the same option I thought while thinking about a solution. What hook would do you use for that? There are quite some, I'm thinking about a pre_post_update.

Comment: 'wp_insert_post_data' can be used to change the post status to draft and create the admin notice. Despite its name it also runs on update. 'pre_post_update' only runs on update not on insert.

Comment: If you know JavaScript you should consider validating in the browser so only valid, consistent data is sent to WordPress. This is probably the best approach if it can be done.